# ClickOnce updates for WPF App installed using MSI

Tags: wpf, windows-installer, clickonce

Is it possible to install a WPF4 Net 4.0 application using a MSI Installer (Advanced Installer) and still leverage ClickOnce's application updates? I'm not talking XBAP but a full desktop app.

I'm asking this question because I've read conflicting statements on the web and here on SO.

Comment: Do you have specific requirements that prevents you from using the ClickOnce installer in the first place? I assume you are aware of the ability to manage prerequisites and including additional files into the ClickOnce installer.

Comment: Yes, the most important one is that I need to run netsh.exe during setup in order to enable a built-in mini webserver based on HttpListener for the current user.

Comment: I've heard several places that this is essentially what Google did/does with the Chrome browser. I'm thinking that if you're ClickOnce application is nothing more than a way of launching the MSI/MSP I don't see why id couldn't be used to install and perhaps even apply updates to the other application. I've done a significant amount of ClickOnce tinkering and have been thoroughly disappointing in the amount of hassle and roadblocks with this technology. If I try it again I'll be attempting the process I described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you wrap that in an MSI and deploy it as a prerequisite to the ClickOnce application?

You can't install an application with an MSI and then use ClickOnce to update it -- it must be installed as a ClickOnce app to start with.

You might be able to zip up the ClickOnce deployment and then unzip it on the customer size and install it from the local folder. If the Installation URL in the manifest is correct, I think that will work. I can't advise further on that, since my expertise is only in ClickOnce deployment.